# Eclipse project explorer can't be switched to the view on working sets

Tags: eclipse

After "project explorer -> view menu -> top level elements -> working sets" being chosen, Eclipse doesn't switch the view from `projects` to `working sets` on `project explorer`. If `package explorer` is used instead, the change-over works fine. Why?

Comment: See https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=220090

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You probably havent selected any working sets. In the drop down menu of the project explorer view, you have a menu item called `select working set...`. Go there and choose what working sets you want to see.

[image: screenshot of project explorer menu]

Comment: Thanks. On `package explorer` there's one more option `other projects` as `default working set` including the projects that aren't yet assigned to `user defined working sets`.

Answer (score 2):

In my situation, I don't want to create any working set. So I change the `Top Level Elements` option(the first item in the drop-down menu of the image on @Fredrik's answer). Just change it from `Working Sets` to `Projects`.